# Is out building universally used?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

In North America we say *out building* for a smaller secondary structure, e.g., on a farm, used for non-human habitation, e.g., storage. Is this also used in Britain? If not, what would be a British English equivalent?

Comment: outbuilding is a single word.

Comment: Be sure to avoid confusion with 'outhouse' which is a more specific smaller secondary structure - ie, a toilet.  I actually thought outbuilding was an americanism for toilet at first read of the question.  Also not used much in Australia.  In Aus, we would normally call outbuildings by their specific name: shed, barn, gazebo etc. Edit: huh, it seems [outhouse](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/outhouse) isn't only for toilets - though it's the only way I've heard it used.

Comment: In [rural] North America maybe. I work on 'buildings' in Chicago for a living. None of them have ever been called an *outbuilding*.

Answer (score 8):

It's usually written as one word, [outbuilding](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/outbuilding). As the dictionary link suggests, it is certainly used and understood in the UK, and would not be considered to be an Americanism or unusual.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/outbuilding) dictionary, it *is* used in British English (note that it's a single word):

> **outbuilding**
> <sub>in British English</sub>
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> a building subordinate to but separate from a main building; *outhouse*

Searching for [`"outbuilding" "uk"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22outbuilding%22+%22uk%22) on Google will give you many "co.uk" (UK) websites which goes to show that the term is definitely used in British English.

Comment: www.designingbuildings. **co.uk** - is the one-boxed top hit on google. "*definitely* used in British English", +1. Not so sure about [urban] North America though. When I google it, they all try to sell me a new garage.